# Can anyone tell whether this RHO step of SHA3 is correct?

Tags: hash, sha-3, keccak

In rho step of SHA3, I have done right circular rotation whether its correct ??
I am doing in Verilog so I am using concatenation operator for rotation.

For x=0 and y=1 that is A[0][1] rotation will be of 36 bits ([See page 22 of the reference](http://keccak.noekeon.org/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf))

```
RotA[0][1] = A[0][1]{[35:28],[63:36],[27:0]};
```

Is this rotation correct??

Comment: I don't know verilog but aren't you missing a part (such as [22:27]) ?

Comment: Ya i wrote it wrong now i have edited it.

Comment: Is this still relevant?  Have you compared to a reference implementation?  How are you laying out the bits and words in your language, and how does it correspond to the layout of bits and words in the Keccak reference?